# Bind selected item in listview to textbox one way not working as expected

Tags: listview, binding, datacontext

The object from the selected item in the listview is bound over DataContext to several textboxes. It works fine, but it update the listview too if the values in the textbox changes. When a user makes a change to a textbox and then select an other item in the listview without clicking the save button, the changes remain. This leads the user to believe that the changes have been adopted from the previous object, which is wrong. the changes in the text boxes should only be applied after the save button has been clicked. I tried:`SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SELECTEDENTRY.Name, Mode=OneWayToSource}"`

Thid didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution, but I don't bind the Textboxes respectively the DataContext-Object to the listview.selecteditem anymore. I load the selected item from the database and store it directly in the DataContext-Object. This works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).